# Skeleton-Avatar and ImageButton in MUI React are forced to oval background shapes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

When using mui Stack I get weird side effect of geting all the background shapes of Skeleton Avatar and background area smeared to oval|elipsoid shapes. I tried setting equal width and height for Avatar but id does not help.

How can I fix it throguh sx mui component property or css?
[image: example of spreaded shapes]

code fragment

```
<Box 
  noValidate autoComplete="off" 
  sx={{ marginLeft: '15%','& .MuiTextField-root': { m: 2, width: '25ch' }}}>
    <div> 
       <form onSubmit={onSubmit} >
         {formFields.map((form, index) => {
           return (
             <Fade in={true} sx = {{width: '95%'}} {...{ timeout: 500 }}>
               <Stack direction="row"  borderRadius="0" spacing={2} key={index} style ={{marginLeft: '-50px', }}>
                 {form.img? <Avatar alt="release img" src={form.img} sx={{ width: 56, height: 56 }} /> : <Skeleton animation={false} variant ='circular'> <Avatar sx={{ width: 56, height: 56}}  /> </Skeleton>}
                 <TextField {/* ... */}/>
                 <IconButton onClick={() => removeFields(index)}><DeleteIcon /</IconButton>
                </Stack>        
              </Fade>
                    )
           })}
        </form>

  <IconButton onClick={addFields} color={'warning'}> <AddCircleOutlineOutlinedIcon /></IconButton>
  <br></br><br></br>
  <Button onClick={onSubmit}  color={'warning'} variant="contained" endIcon= {<SendIcon/>} > Search links </Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the default value of `align-items` for flex items will be `stretch`, that's why you see your icon is stretched in the cross axis

The solution is simple, set `alignItems` prop in `Stack` to a different value rather than `normal`/`stretch`. Here I use `center`

```
       <Stack
          direction="row"
          borderRadius="0"
          spacing={2}
          alignItems="center" // this line
          style={{ marginLeft: "-50px" }}
        >
```

Demo

[image: Edit goofy-yalow-lug341]

#### References

[CSS `align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items)

Comment: Thank you it worked! I tried setting flex options off through system props did not found the right one..